# Understanding Python multiprocessing apply_aync and get

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I was digging through some code that I have written some time ago, and it has the follow construction. I have tried to add explanatory comments where needed.

```py
# Create a reader and a writer process
reader_proc = Process(target=self.reader)
reader_proc.start()

writer_proc = Process(target=self.writer, args=(pfin,))
writer_proc.start()

# start a pool of workers
with Pool(n_workers, maxtasksperchild=max_tasks_per_child) as pool:
    # a list to keep track of workers
    worker_jobs = []
    # a list to keep track of return values
    return_vals = []

    # get input chunks from the reader
    # reader writes input chunks to a work_q (queue)
    while True:
        work = work_q.get()
        if work == 'done':
            break

        # process_chunk is a function that ... processes the given chunk
        # this function will do some computations and write those to a results_q (queue)
        # which the writer will then write to a file
        # the function also returns another type of value that is processed below
        job = pool.apply_async(process_chunk, (work,))
        worker_jobs.append(job)

    print('Done reading chunks!')
    # reader is done reading
    reader_proc.join()
    reader_proc.terminate()

    # When a worker has finished its job, get its information back
    for job_idx, job in enumerate(worker_jobs, 1):
        print(f"Processing job {job_idx}")
        res1, res2 = job.get()
        return_vals.append((res1, res2))

    # process results in main process
    process_results(return_vals)

    # Notify the writer that we're done
    results_q.put('done')
```

Tl;dr a pool processes chunks from a queue with `apply_async`. After the queue is exhausted, we `.get()` the results back and process them.

I am not sure whether the jobs are immediately executed when applied to the pool, or do they wait until `.get()` is called? This is important, because if they wait with execution until after the queue is exhausted, then that can take a long time for long queues.

On the other hand, if they do not wait and execute immediately, then where is the result of those functions stored? Since we are waiting until `.get()` to fetch the results, does that mean a child process is blocked until `.get()` is called?

The reason that I am asking is because there is a very long delay between the first print statement (reading done) and follow ones (processing job x), and I am not sure why.

Comment: You could add a print statement after reader_proc calls just after your "done reading chunks". This is just a guess but the delay might not be caused by your Pool but your manipulation of reader_proc. Could there be a timeout if it is socket code and your .join() would wait unnecessarily long for something?

Comment: @Hannu I did as you suggested and placed a 'Reader terminated' print after the `reader_proc.terminate()` statement, and that was executed immediately, so that's not the issue. I think the issue lies with concurrent reading. When I look at a call graph there's a lot of time spend on waiting for lock. Since I only pass file byte pointers to the subprocesses and not the lines themselves, each subprocess needs to fetch their respective chunk from the same file. I assume that this causes some overhead: opening and closing (and thus, locking) the file.

Comment: Curious.  Even if your slowness was caused by workers being slow and waiting for locks, you still would get the "processing job" message for your first task as you print before getting the result (get will block until a result is actually available).  If you receive *one* processing job print and then a delay, this is what is going on. If you do not receive any of these, then this is a mystery if there is no delay in joining and terminating either.

Comment: You could also try checking job.ready() to see if there actually is a result when you try to `get()` one.   I have never found much use to it in production code but it can help in understanding where any delays are.

Comment: @Hannu exactly what I was thinking. I tried simply `print(job.ready())` but also that waits to be printed. Something is blocking *before* the for loop, but I don't know what since a print statement directly before it is executed immediately. I will not spend time on it anymore, since once it's up and running it does work. But it is curious indeed.

Comment: Just one more even though it doesn't matter anymore... where do you use your reader_proc?  In `work`?  This could be problematic as your workers are busy doing work while you try to kill the reader.   What would happen if you moved your `reader_proc.join()` and `.terminate()` after the get loop?  Functionally that would be the better place for it anyway assuming workers use it and it wouldn't really matter whether you terminate it before or after getting results.

Comment: No, the reader is running in its separate process (outside the pool) and adds chunks to the queue. The queue is read in the main thread, which then distributes the work in the pool. Moving the joining after the work is done makes no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks are executed as soon as a worker is free. Getting the result or not getting it at all does not have an impact on this.

Your worker results are stored in `AsyncResult` objects, in your case `job` is one of these and `worker_jobs` has them all. And then you do the right thing and loop through your result objects and get the results.

Pool stores the results internally until you get them - it does not block a worker even if you do not get the result at all - in many cases of parallel processing you might not even be interested in a "result" from a worker if the worker was only to execute a specific task based on input. As soon as a worker completes and stores the result (or exception!) in this object, it is free to accept another job from the pool.

This also means you must get the results before you close your pool - as you do now. If you moved your "processing job" loop outside your `with Pool...` structure, the results would have been lost by the time you tried to get them.

See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process about available methods of `AsyncResult` object.

The `AsyncResult` object also stores an exception if your worker raises one.  It would not be immediately triggered when a worker encountered an exception but just stored there and raised when you get() the result. If your workers can raise exceptions, you should build exception handling to your get loop instead of the worker.